# How to remove the space between Text Input and Submit Button?

Tags: html, css, forms

Why's there a space between my `submit` and search `field`? How do I get rid of this?

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search..." value="" name="s" title="Search for:" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r303nmLc/)

[image]

Comment: Because there are spaces in the code between those things. There are [ways around that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) but it's generally easiest to just remove the spaces from the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jv655whz/ - and here is a link - http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put them together :)

```
<label>
    <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search up in hur" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" /></label><input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
```

Comment: how would one achieve this in pug/jade?

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this target, first of all put the Button just after Textbox:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search up in hur" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" /><input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
    </label>
</form>
```

Then use this CSS to remove remain space:

```
.search-field, .search-submit{
    margin:0;
}
```

Now there are no space between Button and TextBox but you can see 2px border between them to solve this issue you can add this CSS too:

```
.search-field + .search-submit{
    border:1px solid #a9a9a9;
    border-left:0px;
    height:22px;
}
```

This CSS cause that when a `search-submit` place just after a `search-field` the left border disappear.
So The final result is like this:

[image]

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m8zmf4kp/)**

Answer (score 1):

no need for css just remove indentation or spaces btw the two or more elements and places them on one line

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your CSS will address the issue:

```
label {
    display:inline-block; 
    width: 212px;
}
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r303nmLc/1/)**

The styling is not very pretty...that's why I use bootstrap.  There are built in classes for this in bootstrap.